# Как вывести все действия в фунции слота qt

Tags: c++, qt

Я  знаю, что функции слота кнопки (типа clicked(), pressed() и т.д.) могут вывести вывести только одно последнее описываемое действие. Но мне надо, чтобы все описываемые действия в функции были выведены на экран. 
Например

```
ui->label->setText("some text")
Sleep (1000);
ui->label->setText("some another text");
```

в этом случае на экран будет выведен только "some another text"
Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы выведены были все действия.

Comment: `QTimer.singleShot` + `QEventLoop` вместо `Sleep`, пример на python: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/ru_stackoverflow_exception_questions/dev_script#L126

Comment: `Я знаю, что функции слота кнопки ... могут вывести вывести только одно последнее описываемое действие.` Это не так. Они выводят все, что вы просите, просто из-за цикла обработки событий вы увидите "мгновенную" смену сразу после выхода из метода. Грубый способ исправить это - добавить `QApplication::processEvents();` перед `sleep`.